# Row Index -1 result in Safari and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dhtml

Why I get Row Index -1 result in Safari and Chrome when I try to access a dynamic created table row?

The row is appended with `document.getElementById('tabl').appendChild(rowobject)` and then gets the value of -1 to row Index. Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by "*in* a dynamic created table"? Do you have any relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When referencing the active/selected row in a table, an index of -1 means there is currently no active/selected row. When searching for the row index of a table by the content of some field, a search result of -1 means no such row was found.

This is because tables are 0 index based - meaning the first row is row 0, the second row is row 1, etc. -1 refers explicitly to no row / an invalid row.

Comment: It is fixed when instead of 

document.getElementById('tabl').appendChild(rowobject) 

the append is done with

document.getElementById('tabl').tBodyes[0].appendChild(rowobject)

Here row gets the right index number

Source: [Coding Forums][1]


  [1]: http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-17321.html

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the table, instead of:

```
document.getElementById('tabl').appendChild(rowobject)
```

write:

```
rowobject = document.getElementById('tabl').insertRow(-1);
```

This will append a new row to the end of the table, but the new row will now have a correct index even in Chrome and Safari. You can then use returned reference to the `rowobject` if you want to set some properties to it, such as ID or to append further children such as `td`.

Have a great day :)